# AForge motion detection not detecting motion

Tags: c#, aforge, motion-detection

I'm creating a MotionDetector as below, but it is not detecting motion on a short test video which has motion on it (I am getting VERY small motion levels from the processor). The documentation for AForge is very sketchy and there are very few examples. Is there anything blindingly obvious as to why this isn't detecting very effectively?

```
   detector = new AForge.Vision.Motion.SimpleBackgroundModelingDetector()
    {
        DifferenceThreshold = 25,
        KeepObjectsEdges = true,
        MillisecondsPerBackgroundUpdate = 1000,
        SuppressNoise = true
    };

    processor = new AForge.Vision.Motion.BlobCountingObjectsProcessing()
    {
        HighlightMotionRegions = false,
        MinObjectsHeight = 1,
        MinObjectsWidth = 1
    };

    _motionDetector = new AForge.Vision.Motion.MotionDetector(detector, processor);
```

Comment: Have you seen the example: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/motion_detection_2.0.html. Did it work?